# AndroidStudio - Gives 2 previews of an XML layout, how do I hide the bottom one?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I'm not sure what the layouts are called, but in Android Studio < 3.5 it only display the top one. How can I hide the bottom one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blueprint mode already exists since Android Studio 2.0.

Just click the blue layers icon and select "Design" there:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: perfect, thanks. I regret updating it changed all my previous settings from color scheme to font and layout